# Como atualizar a tela conforme filtro inserido como JavaScript puro na pesquisa?

Tags: javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dados estão dispostos desta forma, porém quero no campo da pesquisa inserir um 'a', então somente aparecer os campos que contém letra 'a'. Mas, se coloco logo 'as', a busca deve ser atualizada. porém está acumulativa. Como atualizar?

```
    let data = null;

request.onload = function() {
    data = JSON.parse(this.response);
}

var filtro = document.getElementById('filtro-pesquisa');

filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;

    data.results.forEach(x => {      
        if((x.name.first.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0) || (x.name.last.toLowerCase().indexOf(nomeFiltro) >= 0)){
            buildCard(x.name, x.gender, x.picture, x.registered);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui, só inserindo uma linha para remover o conteúdo gerado pelo filtro anterior:

```
filtro.onkeyup = function() {
    var nomeFiltro = filtro.value;
    document.getElementById('itemContainer').innerHTML = ""; // linha inserida
    // etc...
```